# What is the "raster fonts" option in windows cmd appearance settings?

Tags: windows, command-line, fonts

I'm trying to make other applications (like putty and SecureCRT) use the same font as windows CMD.

What exactly is this "Raster Fonts" Font and how do I get it?

[image: Windows cmd appearance properties]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Raster fonts** are the same as **Bitmap fonts**, and you can see the Wikipedia definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#Bitmap_fonts).

As for what the font is, you can check the **Selected Font** in the dialog/screenshot above. Your selected font is **terminal**.

Answer (score -1):

There are more **width by height** sizes in the **Raster Fonts** tab than are in terminal. Every font in **Notepad** or **WordPad** has a specific aspect ratio: 1:2* or 1:1. As far as I know, there is no definitive way to get all of the Raster Fonts out of **System32** or even cmd by extracting the fonts RIGHT OUT of cmd using 7-Zip. Yes, 7-Zip can extract out of .exe extensions.

*width:height