# Notepad on Windows 11 not respecting Unicode monospace characters

Tags: windows, fonts, unicode, notepad

I'm using box-drawing characters to represent trees. I need other people using Windows to see them so I can assume they all have Notepad installed. But even if I select Consolas as the font, here's what my tree looks like:

[image]

The same tree on Notepad++ looks like:

[image]

For some reason Notepad is making the box-drawing characters wider. Is there any alternative font or setting I could change to make it look right?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Is this a font called System? Can't find any with this name on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [**raster** (bitmap)](https://superuser.com/questions/504026/what-is-the-raster-fonts-option-in-windows-cmd-appearance-settings) font. Unlike scalable TrueType fonts, a bitmap font specifies *exactly* the color of each pixel in a grid. If a character is designed to be the full height of the line, with no [leading](https://www.indesignskills.com/tutorials/leading-typography/) (word is from the metal *lead*, inserted to add space). BTW, "raster" is a misnomer from the days when cathode ray tube (CRT) displays were scanned in *raster* lines.

However, that font would have to be used by both parties, if you're sharing the screen output. The recipient would need to set *System* in Notepad, or *Raster Fonts* in CMD.

[image: Notepad raster (bitmap) fonts]

[image: CMD raster (bitmap) fonts]